# Include Jar in ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to compile my project with a build.xml script. At the moment it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="vml" default="main" basedir=".">
  <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
  <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
  <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
  <property name="build.dir" location="bin" />
  <property name="libs.dir" location="libs" />
  <property name="dist.dir" location="build/jar" />
  <property name="docs.dir" location="build/docs" />

  <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
  <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
    </javac>

  </target>

  <!-- Creates Javadoc -->
  <target name="docs" depends="compile">
    <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
      <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
       <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**" />
           </fileset>
    </javadoc>
  </target>

  <!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
  <target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\test.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="vml.coding.test.Test" />
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>

  <target name="main" depends="compile, jar, docs">
    <description>Main target</description>
  </target>

</project>
```

It doesn't work because I am using a couple of external libs (.jar), so I get this compilation error:

```
error: package com.opencsv does not exist
    [javac] import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
```

This is my folder hierarchy:

```
project
|
|-src
|-build
|-libs
```

Those jar are inside libs.

I have tried adding this to the build.xml with no luck:

```
    ...
    <path id="build-classpath">
      <fileset dir="${libs.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
    </path>
    ...
    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
      <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\test.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
        <manifest>
          <attribute name="Main-Class" value="vml.coding.test.Test" />
          <attribute name="Build-Path" value="${build-classpath}" />
        </manifest>
      </jar>
    </target>
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: For the record I recommend you to take a look at [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
dkatzel pointed me on the right direction. Finally I managed to make it works and this is how it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="vml" default="main" basedir=".">
    <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
    <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="bin" />
    <property name="libs.dir" location="libs" />
    <property name="dist.dir" location="build/jar" />
    <property name="docs.dir" location="build/docs" />
    <path id="build-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${libs.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
    </target>
    <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
    <target name="makedir">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
    </target>
    <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
    <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
            <classpath refid="build-classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>
    <!-- Creates Javadoc -->
    <target name="docs" depends="compile">
        <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
            <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
            <classpath refid="build-classpath" />
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**" />
            </fileset>
        </javadoc>
    </target>
    <!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\test.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="${libs.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="vml.coding.test.Test" />
                <attribute name="Build-Path" value="${build-classpath}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="main" depends="compile, jar, docs">
        <description>Main target</description>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is happening in your compile target not your jar target.

You are right that you need to use a `path` to add the jars to the classpath, but then you need to reference it in your compile target javac task:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" 
            classpathref="build-classpath"
 />
```

You probably also want to incldue your build dir so classes can reference each other?

```
<path id="build-classpath">
  <fileset dir="${libs.dir}">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
  <pathelement path= "${build.dir}"/>
</path>
```

You will then need to make sure those jars are in your classpath again when you try to execute your jar.